# External hard disk not found

Tags: external-hdd

I use my external hard disk to be bootable. I just bought a external hard disk. I flashed ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso to my external hard disk and it worked very well. But when I installed Ubuntu it takes a very long time (it take about a day to install but it wasn't even halfway through) so while it was installing I force quit it about 2-3times but this time I force quite it again because it was taking a very long time to install. I got stuck at Creating ext4 file system for /home in partition #7 of SCSI2 (0,0,0) (sda).

And then I restarted my laptop again but now it shows no bootable disk, I moveed to MacBook and it doesn't show the same bootable, I opened  Disk Utility and it doesn't show my external hard disk.

What has happened and how can I fix it.

[image: laptop]

[image: MacBook]

[image: Disk Utility]

Comment: Were you installing from hard disk to hard disk. Usually you use a smaller 8 or 16GB flash drive to extract ISO into as most tools that extract ISO totally erase entire drive. Many of the tools use dd or dd under the hood. Using dd typically erases the entire partition table area as the ISO is then a hybrid DVD/flash drive configuration. If using a large drive, often better to just create an ESP - efi system partition FAT32 with boot,esp flags and extract ISO into it. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Re-use_the_pendrive